# SQL/Navision DateTime Issue

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-dynamics, navision

I don't know if anyone else has experiencing this issue before

I have DateTime Data in a MsSQl table but when displaying the same data in Navison 2013, it is displaying the time wrongly. 
`2018-12-14 08:20:22.000` is being displayed as `14-12-18 11:20:22 AM`

Any suggestions ?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Looks like some kind of time zone conversion.

Comment: Check  current time zone difference with SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE());

Answer (score 3):

The time stored in the SQL database will be stored in UTC. However, since you're based in Kenya (I assume from your profile), your time zone is UTC+3. Navision  (Dynamics NAV) automatically converts UTC time into your local time zone.

So if you're writing to the database directly without going through Navision you should use UTC time to save the time.